# Very Simple matrix calculation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, tensor-products

I need to prove that, given $f$ a vector valued function from $B_1(0) \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$, we have that (knowing that $\partial_{\nu}f = Df \cdot \frac{x}{|x|}$)

$$\langle Df , Df \cdot x \otimes \frac{x}{|x|}\rangle = |\partial_{\nu}f|^2 |x|.$$

I understand that $x \otimes \frac{x}{|x|}$ is a rank one $m \times m$ matrix, hence I get just by dividing and subtracting
$$\langle Df , Df \cdot \frac{x}{|x|} \otimes \frac{x}{|x|}\rangle \, |x|,$$ hence

$$\langle Df , \partial_{\nu}f \cdot \frac{x^T}{|x|}\rangle \, |x|.$$
From here I cannot understand how to justify that I can put on the left the $\frac{x^T}{|x|}$ term. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f:B_1(0)\subseteq \mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^m$ be given and define the upgraded *directional derivative*:
$$\partial_{\nu}f:= Df\cdot \frac{x}{|x|} = Df\bigg(\frac{x}{|x|}\bigg),$$
where $Df := \big[\partial_jf_i(x)\big]_{ij}$ is the *Jacobian matrix*, each row being the gradient of $f_i$.
And define the **Hilbert-Schmidt** *inner-product* of matrices as:
$$\langle A,B\rangle = Tr(A^*B) = \sum\limits_{j=1}^m\langle Ae_j,Be_j\rangle,$$
for the usual orthonormal basis, $\{e_i\}$, on $\mathbb{R}^m$ ($A^* = A^t$ here). Then we want to show:
$$\color{darkblue}{\langle Df,Df\cdot x\otimes \frac{x}{|x|}\rangle = |\partial_{\nu}f|^2|x|},$$
where lastly $a\otimes b := a\cdot b^t\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$.

---

Accordingly, using the definitions and *multi-linearity* of tensor products, matrices, and our particular inner product:
$$\big\langle Df,Df\cdot x\otimes \frac{x}{|x|}\big\rangle = \sum\limits_{j=1}^m\big\langle Df\cdot e_j,\big(Df\cdot x\otimes \frac{x}{|x|}\big)\cdot e_j\big\rangle$$
$$= \sum\limits_{j=1}^m\big\langle Df\cdot e_j, (Df\cdot x)\frac{x^t}{|x|}\cdot e_j\big\rangle$$
$$= \sum\limits_{j=1}^m\big\langle Df\cdot e_j, (Df\cdot x)\frac{x^j}{|x|}\big\rangle$$
$$= \sum\limits_{j=1}^m\big\langle Df\cdot (e_j\cdot \frac{x^j}{|x|}), Df\cdot x\big\rangle$$
$$= \big\langle Df\cdot \frac{x}{|x|}, Df\cdot x\big\rangle$$
$$= \big\langle Df\cdot \frac{x}{|x|}, Df\cdot \frac{x}{|x|}\big\rangle|x|$$
$$= |\partial_{\nu}f|^2|x|.$$

---

*Thanks to @Son Gohan and @Crash Bandicoot (4!) for the suggestions/clarification of the HS inner product and notations.*

Comment: Let me accept your answer, as a reward for the time spent. I’d accept Son Gohan’s answer as well if I could.

Answer (score 2):

Do not get confused between the matrix-vector product and the Hilbert-Schmidt product, which for vectors coincide. Kevin's computations are fair if we consider scalar-valued functions only. In the vectorial case we have the following:

$$ \langle Df,  Df\cdot x\otimes\frac{x}{|x|}\rangle=\langle Df,  \partial_{\nu}f \cdot \frac{x^T}{|x|}\rangle$$

$$=\sum_{k=1}^m \nabla f_k \cdot \partial_{\nu}f_k \cdot \frac{x^T}{|x|}$$

$$=\sum_{k=1}^m \nabla f_k \cdot \frac{x}{|x|} \cdot (\partial_{\nu}f_k)^{T}$$

$$ \langle Df \cdot \frac{x}{|x|},  \partial_{\nu}f\rangle= |\partial_{\nu}f|^2.$$

---

Or simply, by definition of Hilbert-Schmidt norm:

$$ \langle Df,  Df\cdot x\otimes\frac{x}{|x|}\rangle=\langle Df,  \partial_{\nu}f \cdot \frac{x^T}{|x|}\rangle$$

$$= \text{Tr}\left(Df\cdot (\partial_{\nu}f \cdot \frac{x^T}{|x|})^T\right)$$ $$ = \text{Tr}\left(Df\cdot  \frac{x}{|x|} \cdot(\partial_{\nu}f)^T \right)$$

$$= \text{Tr}\left(\partial_{\nu}f \cdot(\partial_{\nu}f)^T \right)$$ $$=\langle\partial_{\nu}f,\partial_{\nu}f \rangle =|\partial_{\nu}f|^2.  $$

Comment: Now it's clearer! Thank you very much to both of you!